# Create a form validation error instead of the yellow page error message DJANGO MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, class, validation, model

I have been trying to solve this forever now, tried 20+ stackoverflow solutions but nothing fits.

I am trying to figure out how to set an initial value for MultipleChoiceField. and then disable it for the user so that it shows form validation error in the HTML page {{forms.errors}} instead of the yellow page error message.

Models:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,validators=[check_unique])
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(10)])
    review = models.TextField(validators=[RegexValidator('^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$', message='Only Alphanumeric Characters')])
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

here's the unique key :

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'entry')
```

it has user and entry as foreign keys.
What I want is when 1 user adds a review for an entry for the second time he should be shown an error message

> " you can add only 1 review to this entry ".

I have tried this several ways.

case 1 : tried to collect entry from url kwargs, send it to forms and set initial value

views.py

```
class ReviewCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class = ReviewForm
    template_name = 'myapp/review_form.html'
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        entry = self.kwargs.get('entry')
        kwargs = super(ReviewCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'entry': entry})
        return kwargs
```

forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['entry','rating','review']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        entry = kwargs.pop('entry', None)
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        new = str(entry)
        entry_object = Entry.objects.get(slug=str(entry))
        entry_id=entry_object.name
        obj = str(entry_object)
        #tried both : 
        #self.fields['entry'].initial = obj
        self.initial['entry'] = obj
```

didn't work. if i try to `print(select.inital['entry'])` it shows the correct value. but when I browse the html page it shows `-----------` and then the complete list in the drop down.

case 2 :

tried to set this in forms.py but no luck :

```
form = ReviewForm(initial = { 'entry' : Entry.Object.get(slug=entry) })
```

Ideal scenario I want : it should show the selected entry instead of ------- and should be disabled. and if the review is not unique. it should show a FORM validationerror instead of a yellow page error.

Edit : HTML page as requested :

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% include 'myapp/form-template.html' %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

include :

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
     {{field.label_tag}}
 {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
{{field.errors}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
<p class="errornote">
    {{ error }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: show your html, did you use any plugins for render select on the front? if use try disable and the test.

Comment: @BearBrown even if I figure out how to do that, that shall be done after the initial tag works. Which is also not working as mentioned. So even if we disable it will show ------- as disabled.